# How can I track position during jquery hover? Not after stop()

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a sliding list of items to mimic netflix. Looking at their source code I have the html markup figured out and I think I have the concept for it pretty much figured out. I just need to be able to track the css right position during hover and do other things with it via another function while the hovering is happening rather than after the hover stops.

**Edit:** More detail on the concept I'm trying to achieve. I will need to do two things while the "set" is sliding.

1. When a "item' slides off screen it needs to be removed from the set and then re-inserted at the other end of the set so I need a way to know when it has gone off the screen in either direction.
2. I need to know when the set has slid it's full length in either direction so I can reset its position.

The only way I can think to achieve this illusion of a endlessly scrolling set is to track the css position while the set is sliding. I can handle the rest I think but just need to know how to plug into the .hover() or some other way to track it without interrupting .hover().

I'm open to suggestions of other methods if .hover isn't appropriate.

Here is my code

HTML:

```
<div id="slider">
            <div class="set">
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/book.png">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/book.png">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/book.png">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/book.png">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/book.png">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/book.png">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/book.png">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/book.png">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/book.png">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/book.png">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/book.png">
                </div>
            </div><!--end set-->

            <div class="prevBtn"></div>
            <div class="nextBtn"></div>
        </div><!--end slider-->
```

slider.js:

```
(function() {

    var Slider = {

        init: function() {
            var set = $('#slider .set'),
            setLength = set.children().length * 190,

            prev = $('.prevBtn'),
            next = $('.nextBtn');
            self = this;


            prev.hover(function() {
                set
                    .css({right: set.position().right})
                    .animate({right: '-' + setLength + 'px'}, 8000);
            }, function() {
                set.stop();
            });

            next.hover(function() {
                set
                    .css({left: set.position().right})
                    .animate({right: setLength + 'px'}, 8000);
            }, function() {
                set.stop();
            });
        }
    }


    Slider.init();
}());
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found this [jquery watch plugin](https://github.com/darcyclarke/jQuery-Watch-Plugin) which answered the question of tracking the left position. It is limited because it only checks for DomAttrModified or propertychange and otherwise runs a timer to check the position on intervals which I really don't want for performance reasons. Looks like the replacement will be 'mutation observers' although it doesn't seem to have enough browser support yet.

But then I found this [marquee plugin](https://github.com/aamirafridi/jQuery.Marquee) which ends up with less code than trying to track the position and perform all kinds of crazy math, speed calculations, determining direction,  and removing/appending images. Where I was going was looking more and more over complicated. So I think I'm going to go with this second solution. I was able to modify it by replacing it's setInterval with my hover functions to change the direction based on which button is hovered and run/stop the animation.

I'll use this and rewrite for this specific purpose and post it here in the next day or two.